# JavaScript Regex Global Match Groups

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

**Update:** This question is a near duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex)

I'm sure the answer to my question is out there, but I couldn't find the words to express it succinctly. I am trying to do the following with JavaScript regex:

```
var input = "'Warehouse','Local Release','Local Release DA'";
var regex = /'(.*?)'/g;

console.log(input.match(regex));

// Actual:
// ["'Warehouse'", "'Local Release'", "'Local Release DA'"]

// What I'm looking for (without the '):
// ["Warehouse", "Local Release", "Local Release DA"]
```

Is there a clean way to do this with JavaScript regex? Obviously I could strip out the `'`s myself, but I'm looking for the correct way to caputre globally matched groupings with regex.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you access the matched groups in a javascript regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex)

Comment: Yep, it's definitely a duplicate, I wasn't sure how to search for my question :/

Comment: I found it by searching for _[javascript] [regex] global capture group_.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

To do this with a regex, you will need to iterate over it with `.exec()` in order to get multiple matched groups.  The `g` flag with match will only return multiple whole matches, not multiple sub-matches like you wanted.  Here's a way to do it with `.exec()`.

```
var input = "'Warehouse','Local Release','Local Release DA'";
var regex = /'(.*?)'/g;

var matches, output = [];
while (matches = regex.exec(input)) {
    output.push(matches[1]);
}
// result is in output here
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/VSczR/

---

With certain assumptions about what's in the strings, you could also just use this:

```
var input = "'Warehouse','Local Release','Local Release DA'";
var output = input.replace(/^'|'$/, "").split("','");
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/MFNm3/

---

**Note:** With modern Javascript engines as of 2021, you can use [`str.matchAll(regex)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) and get all matches in one function call.

Comment: Added a non-regex way to also do this.

Comment: I applied this loop with this regex `/<img[^>]+?src=(?:(?:'([^']*)')|(?:"([^"]*)")|([^\s]*))/i` and console don't respond and chrome using 1 full cpu core

Comment: Oh I forgot the `g` modifier. Now it's ok

Comment: this will fail in jslink.. do this instead 

while ((matches = regex.exec(input)) !== null){

Comment: @keithics - What in the world is jslink returning that is not `null`, but is falsey that would make the original code not work?  This is weird.  `.exec()` should return an array or `null` so the original code should detect no match just fine.

Comment: @keithics - OK, there's nothing wrong with the code then.  That's just a false warning.  Given we know what `.exec()` returns, the code is no better or safer by changing to `!== null`.  That's just an overcautious warning by jsHint.

Comment: [Mozilla uses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) `!== null`

Comment: The code goes into infinite loop when the pattern matches the empty string, e.g. `regex = /.*/g`.

Comment: @umitu - You'd have to explain what exact problem you're trying to solve using that regex (perhaps write your own question).   That regex matches the entire string.   These days [`.matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) can often be used instead of a loop, but again, I don't really know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @jfriend00 When I tried to match text inside parentheses with `regex = /(?<=\()[^)]*(?=\))/g`, I got an infinite loop with `"()"`. matchAll() works fine.

Answer (score 11):

[`String.prototype.matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) is now [well supported in modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=string%20matchall) as well as [Node.js.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#Browser_compatibility) This can be used like so:

```
const matches = Array.from(myString.matchAll(/myRegEx/g)).map(match => match[1]);
```

Note that the passed `RegExp` must have the global flag or an error will be thrown.

Conveniently, this does not throw an error when no matches are found as `.matchAll` always returns an iterator (vs `.match()` returning `null`).

---

For this specific example:

```
var input = "'Warehouse','Local Release','Local Release DA'";
var regex = /'(.*?)'/g;

var matches = Array.from(input.matchAll(regex)).map(match => match[1]);
// [ "Warehouse", "Local Release", "Local Release DA" ]
```

Comment: `Array.from` accepts a `mapFn` as a second argument. So what's also possible is: `Array.from(myString.matchAll(/myRegEx/g), m => m[1])`. MDN uses it as an example in their `matchAll` documentation, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll

Answer (score 9):

There is an ECMAScript proposal called [`String.prototype.matchAll()`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-matchall) that would fulfill your needs.

Comment: It looks like this is already well supported! Sweet!

Comment: That's right: https://caniuse.com/?search=String.prototype.matchAll

Answer (score 5):

Not very generic solution since lookbehind isn't supported in Javascript but for given input this regex should work:

```
m = input.match(/([^',]+)(?=')/g);
//=> ["Warehouse", "Local Release", "Local Release DA"]
```

Answer (score 3):

With es2020 you can use [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll):

```
var input = "'Warehouse','Local Release','Local Release DA'";
var regex = /'(.*?)'/g;

const match_all = [...input.matchAll(regex)];
```

If you're using typescript, don't forget to set it in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2020.string"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like `input.replace(regex, "$1")` to get the results of your capture group.

Comment: To get into array - `input.replace(regex, "$1").split(',')`

Comment: OP wants the result in an array.

Comment: I like your line of thinking, assuming the content doesn't have an `,`s in it.

Comment: @Jondlm can do - `regex = /'(.*?)'(,?)/g;` and `input.replace(regex, "$1$2$2").split(',,')`

Answer (score -1):

this regex works but with defined characters...

```
var input = "'Warehouse','Local Release','Local Release DA'";

var r =/'[\w\s]+'/gi;
console.log(input.match(regex));
```

Comment: This leaves the single quote marks in the result which is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: This won't work in javascript, but it does work in java. Sorry bout that.

yes, it's called a **"look ahead"** and a **"look behind"**

```
(?<=').*?(?=')
```

- (?=') looks ahead for the '
- (?<=') looks behind for the '

test it out [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Comment: in javascript there is no look behind.

Comment: So why write it then, knowing it doesn't work in Javascript? Otherwise people would ask with a Java tag. Beggar's belief...

Comment: There is look behind in JavaScript now

Comment: Here is an article about how to use lookbehind and lookahed: https://v8.dev/blog/regexp-lookbehind-assertions