# Regular expression to determine URL video ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match

I would like to use a regular expression to determine the video ID of NHL.com videos.

Example urls are the following:

```
1. http://video.nhl.com/videocenter/console?id=789500&catid=35
2. http://video.senators.nhl.com/videocenter/console?id=790130&catid=1141
3. http://video.nhl.com/videocenter/?id=2013020884-605-h
```

From these examples, the values I would need are as follows:

```
1. 789500
2. 790130
3. 2013020884-605-h
```

I would like to use the match() function to obtain the ID following `?id=`, the ID's can include characters that are alphanumeric, underscore, and dash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
/\?id=([^&]+)/gi
```

i.e.

```
var re = /[?&]id=([^&#]+)/i;
```

And use matched group #1:

```
var m = str.match(re);
var id = m[1];
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rB8wD1/1)

Comment: Global matches via `.match()` [don't include groups in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913667/javascript-regex-global-match-groups). In addition, the regex should probably be changed to match a question mark _or an ampersands_ at the beginning. In addition, leave out any hash tags at the end in case of a fragment identifier in the URL. For instance: `/[?&]id=([^&#]+)/i`