# Different between /{.*?}/g. and /{(.*?)}/g

Tags: javascript, regex

In Chrome,

```
/{.*?}/g.exec('aaa{eee}uuuu')
```

returns

```
["{eee}"]
```

, whereas

```
/{(.*?)}/g.exec('aaa{eee}uuuu')
```

returns

```
["{eee}", "eee"]
```

The second result is what I expected. Why not the first code return the naked string of "{eee}"?

Comment: Because u captured it in second case using `()` and not in first case

Comment: Why did you expect that result if you didn't place a [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in your expression?

Comment: I didn't know the word and the concept "capturing". Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in first regex you did not used braces. braces is used to group the string passed but in second regex you have used braces which group "eee" according to your input.

First regex returns array with only one element that matches. but in second expression it return array with 2 element . [0] => whole string matched, [1] => string matched inside braces. If more braces are used then it will return [2] =>  ...,[3] => ... , etc

refer:  [JavaScript Regex Global Match Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913667/javascript-regex-global-match-groups)

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913667/javascript-regex-global-match-groups

Comment: it wont throw error but return array with only one element that matches. but in second expression it return array with 2 element . [0] => whole string matched, [1] => string matched inside braces. If more braces are used then it will return [2] =>  ...,[3] => ... , etc