# Regular Expression in Google Apps Script 2

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having a text file and need to extract words and figures out of it. The Script searches for a keyword and takes the word/figure after the keyword.

This is where i get the result from filter:

```
var ergebnis=text.match(filter[i]);
```

These are the regular expressions:

```
var filter=[/ISIN (\w*)/g, /STK (\w*)/g , /(Kurs) EUR/g];
```

The regular expression works with the single words `ISIN` and `STK`, but fails with the expression `Kurs EUR`.

I have tried various expressions without getting a match. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

### Brief

You're using [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead of [`exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec): See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214754/what-is-the-difference-between-regexp-s-exec-function-and-string-s-match-fun) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913667/javascript-regex-global-match-groups) for more information.

From `match()` documentation:

> **If the regular expression does not include the `g` flag, `str.match()`
>   will return the same result as `RegExp.exec()`**. The returned `Array` has
>   an extra `input` property, which contains the original string that was
>   parsed. In addition, it has an index property, which represents the
>   zero-based index of the match in the string.
>
> **If the regular expression includes the `g` flag, the method returns an
>   `Array` containing all matched substrings rather than match objects.
>   Captured groups are not returned.** If there were no matches, the method
>   returns `null`.

From `exec()` documentation:

> If the match succeeds, the `exec()` method returns an array and updates
>   properties of the regular expression object. **The returned array has
>   the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each
>   capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was
>   captured**.

---

### Code

#### Method 1 - Using exec()

The snippet below shows how to use `exec()` instead of `match()` to output the matched strings and their respective groups.

```js
var array = [
  "ISIN Something",
  "STK Something_2",
  "Kurs EUR"
]
var filter=[
  /ISIN (\w*)/g,
  /STK (\w*)/g ,
  /(Kurs) EUR/g
];

array.forEach(function(s) {
  filter.forEach(function(f) {
    var m = f.exec(s)
    if (m) {
      console.log(`String: ${m[0]}\nGroup: ${m[1]}`)
    }
  })
})
```

#### Method 2 - Removing g flag

The snippet below shows how to use `match()` to output the matched strings and their respective groups by removing the `g` modifier. As per the documentation (quoted in the **Brief** section), this *will return the same result as `RegExp.exec()`*.

```js
var array = [
  "ISIN Something",
  "STK Something_2",
  "Kurs EUR"
]
var filter=[
  /ISIN (\w*)/,
  /STK (\w*)/ ,
  /(Kurs) EUR/
];

array.forEach(function(s) {
  filter.forEach(function(f) {
    var m = s.match(f)
    if (m) {
      console.log(`String: ${m[0]}\nGroup: ${m[1]}`)
    }
  })
})
```