# Regex for returning text after = sign before )

Tags: javascript

This regex is supposed to capture what's after the `=` sign and what's before the `)`.

Why does it return both the = and ) in the output. Is this how it works? Or am I doing something wrong?

```js
const s = '=foo)';
console.log(s.match(/=(.*)\)/g))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to match multiple instances and you want to get what's in the capturing group then you get get rid of the `g` flag and retrieve solely the capturing group:

```js
const s = '=foo)';
console.log(s.match(/=(.*)\)/)[1]);
```

Comment: And if there are multiple instances?

Comment: And if multiple matches are needed, you can use [`exec`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19913702/1913729) instead