# Get repo name and pull number from GitHub url

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to use Regex to extract the repository name and pull request number from a url.

```js
const paragraph = 'https://github.com/johndoe/awesome-repo/pull/12';
const regex = /https:\/\/github.com\/johndoe\/([a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+)\/pull\/(\d+)/gm;
const found = paragraph.match(regex);

console.log(found);
// expected output: Array ["awesome-repo", "12"]
```

But the response is just the entire url `> Array ["https://github.com/johndoe/awesome-repo/pull/12"]`

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Try it omitting the `/gm` flags, then the matches are in group 1 and 2 like `console.log(found[1]);`

Answer (score 0):

**To only get the desired matching groups:**

you could destructure to variables like:

```js
const url = 'https://github.com/johndoe/awesome-repo/pull/12';
const [all, name, pull] = url.match(/([^\/]+)\/pull\/(\d+)$/);

console.log([name, pull]); // ["awesome-repo", "12"]
```

or without the matching groups:

```js
const url = 'https://github.com/johndoe/awesome-repo/pull/12';
const result = url.match(/[^\/]+(?=\/pull\/)|\d+$/g);

console.log(result); // ["awesome-repo", "12"]
```

---

Your regex expressed the entire string (from `https`... to the last character in its entirety) when using the `g` (*global*) flag, consuming it and matching it. Therefore the first match will be the entire matching string. Remove the `g` (and the `m` *multiline*) to **also** collect the  **two matching groups** `()` matches:

```js
const paragraph = 'https://github.com/johndoe/awesome-repo/pull/12';
const regex = /https:\/\/github.com\/johndoe\/([a-zA-Z]+-[a-zA-Z]+)\/pull\/(\d+)/;
const found = paragraph.match(regex);

console.log(found); // ["https://github.com/johndoe/awesome-repo/pull/12", "awesome-repo", "12"]
```

Answer (score -1):

If using the global regex-flag (`/g`), the groups are not included. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913667/javascript-regex-global-match-groups). In your example you can simple omit both flags. Also, you can match the repo-name without defining the character-sets. Your regexp needs a dash `-` and cannot work on repos with numbers in it...

```js
const paragraph = 'https://github.com/johndoe/awesome-repo/pull/12';
const regex = /https:\/\/github.com\/johndoe\/([^\/]+)\/pull\/(\d+)/;
const found = paragraph.match(regex);

console.log(found);
// expected output: Array ["awesome-repo", "12"]
// output: ["https://github.com/johndoe/awesome-repo/pull/12", "awesome-repo", "12", index: 0, input: "https://github.com/johndoe/awesome-repo/pull/12", groups: undefined]
```